# The null space vector of matrix means that it is orthogonal to the the matrix?

Tags: matrices, orthogonal-matrices

If now there is a matrix $\mathbf H$,and assume it has null space vector,that is $\vec n \mathbf H=\vec 0$.

Now if i want to find a vector $\vec v$ which is orthogonal to $\mathbf H$.So is $\vec v =\vec n$?

Comment: There is no such thing as being "orthogonal to a matrix". What do you really mean?

Comment: the vector multiply a matrix will become a zero vector

Comment: Then you're asking whether a null space vector is a null space vector? If you want $vH=0$, and you know $nH=0$, then you can take $v$ to be $n$. $n$ is not the only choice for $v$, but it's certainly one choice for $v$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. $nH=0$ and $vH=0$ does not imply $v=n$. For example, $nH=0$ and $(2n)H=0$ but $n\neq 2n$ (assuming $n\neq0$). If only the zero vector $n=0$ gives $nH=0$, then $nH=0$ and $vH=0$ implies $n=v=0$.